# Tag asking for translation

Tags: feature-request, tags

I wanted to tag [a question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/filtering-based-on-activities-inside-the-video-blocks-and-at-their-boundary-us65) to request for a [BS-free translation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2013/07/22.html)  (a more specific example [here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/filtering-based-on-activities-inside-video-blocks-nokia-issued-patent-prio/4687#4687)).  There wasn't any obvious tag for this.

[Again](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/break-down-by-claim-or-patent), I think this translation request somewhat breaks the Q/A format, maybe there could be a 2-stage process?

At the very least, I think such a tag should get a special graphic akin to the prior-art tag  : )

Comment: The question you linked to is long and relates to multiple patents each with multiple claims. What style of "translation" do you recommend?

Comment: I added [this link](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/filtering-based-on-activities-inside-video-blocks-nokia-issued-patent-prio/4687#4687) to an example I did previously.  Does that help?