# Auto-import Claims

Tags: feature-request

This is aimed towards improving the workflow for [translating patent claims](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/break-down-by-claim-or-patent).

I would like to have SE auto-import and format the top-level claims for patents.  We could use the [European Patent Office API](https://developers.epo.org/) to fetch the claims (use `http://ops.epo.org/3.1/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/US7149251/claims` for a GET request) and copy the independent claims using heuristics (position, length, and/or the first sentence not including "according to claim X").