# Why can I not comment on Question 47?

Tags: support

I wanted to add my comments to

[How Do I Write a Prior Art Request for a U.S. Patent Application?](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47)

but the "**add comment**" link does not appear on either on the question nor on the first anwser.

Why is that?

I understand that the first answer is a "community wiki" post and as such a user needs 100 reputation to edit it. But the FAQ [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) does not say anything about reputations needed for commenting.

Only https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges mentions commenting and it says that 1 reputation is enough to get the privilege "comment everywhere".

Please help me understand the intricacies of stack exchange's policies. Thanks.

PS: This is a screenshot of the page referenced above from my point of view:
[image]

Comment: Please forgive me for asking what sounds a lot like a stupid question, but... are you sure you're logged in?

Comment: @AnnaLear: Yes, I was logged in. I added a screenshot as proof. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: I just tried to post a comment to that question. I can't post one there either.

Answer (score 1):

I have plenty of rep. points and I can't post a comment in either of those places either.

Comment: Very interesting observation. Obviously @MicahSiegel is able to add comments, at least to my answer to question #47.